# Upgraded Rails app to Ruby 1.9.2 - class DateTime needs to have method `_load'

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activesupport

Since I upgraded my app to ruby 1.9.2 I got the following error :

I'm running ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin11.2.0]

```
TypeError (class DateTime needs to have method `_load'):
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:45:in `load'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb:45:in `verify'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:288:in `[]'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:53:in `block in unpacked_cookie_data'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:55:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb:51:in `unpacked_cookie_data'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/cookie.rb:98:in `extract_session_id'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `block in extract_session_id'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:55:in `stale_session_check!'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:51:in `extract_session_id'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:43:in `load_session_id!'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:32:in `[]'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:262:in `current_session_id'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:268:in `session_exists?'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:107:in `exists?'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:122:in `load_for_read!'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:64:in `has_key?'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:258:in `ensure in call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:259:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__3195440498508246587__call__1658952344890015472__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/guillaumenm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /Users/guillaumenm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /Users/guillaumenm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

I created a new rails App, no issues launching it. I was not having any issues before.

Here's my gem file. Any help would be very welcome.

Thanks

```
source :gemcutter

gem 'oauth2'
gem 'faraday'
gem "koala", "~> 1.2.0beta"
gem 'json'
gem "rails", "3.2.1"
gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3" 
gem 'songkickr'
gem 'httparty'
gem "squeel" , "~> 0.9.5" 
group :development do
  gem 'dalli'  #To use memcached
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'rails-web-console', :require => 'console'
  gem 'heroku'
end

gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'
gem 'delayed_job', '2.1.4'
gem 'icalendar'
gem 'acts_as_tree'
gem 'active_scaffold'
gem 'prototype-rails' 
gem 'prototype_legacy_helper', '0.0.0'  , :git => 'git://github.com/rails/prototype_legacy_helper.git'
gem "state_machine"
```

Just downgraded my app to my previous working rails 3.1.2, no more success. Related to ruby 1.9.2 upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on stackoverflow :

[Local server error after upgrading ruby from 1.8.7 to 1.9.2 (with Rails 3.1.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013921/local-server-error-after-upgrading-ruby-from-1-8-7-to-1-9-2-with-rails-3-1-1)

Clear your cookies: your app is storing the session (which is a marshalled ruby object) in a cookie. If i remember correctly he marshal format changed between 1.8 and 1.9, so your app can no longer load old sessions

A chance my app was not a production app, or I could've had many users getting these errors...

Answer (score 0):

While updating a production app, I was able to work around the issue by clearing all sessions:

## DELETE FROM sessions;

(from the DB using SQL -- so the users don't have to clear their cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me recently. After some debugging (even debugging the ruby code to confirm), my conclusion was that the plist4r gem was modifying the String class, making it user-serializable (). After an update, when we dropped our dependency of plist4r, the String instances were reverted back to system-deserializable. But the serialized streams still required String instances to be user-deserializable hence the error.

For me it was the case of plist4r and String class https://github.com/dreamcat4/plist4r/blob/master/lib/plist4r/backend/ruby_cocoa.rb

There might be some other cases as well.

The solution for us was to invalidate all the sessions (data/cookies) thus removing the need to deserialize those streams.